# Implementing multi layer role on Django

Tags: python, django, django-permissions

Working with django Group and Permission. Normally works fine. Now want to add sub admin who can give permission only particular model. How to implement?

Comment: You need to implement this custom and apply decorators wherever applicable and study the Django-Admin permission, it's actually simple but time consuming.

Comment: can you show any example

Comment: I had same issue in one of my project, where there were admin but I want to put one more admin under each company so, I added one more layer after Djanog-Admin and I studied that and by using decorators if directly wants to reject use and common functions to return dict of permissions list to dyanamically handle at Djanog-Admin end.

Comment: Same Issue. Each company can set role. It would be helpful if u give snippet

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion below are my Steps:

1. Override Role with company OR you can keep this at Super Admin level.
   http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/role/
2. Add separate table for permissions with pk, client ID, RoleID , add, edit, view, delete, model, action (URL) columns
3. Add decorator for each of the action or Model and check permissions for that particular action or model.
4. Check roles and permission in Admin using common function something like `check_role_permissions_admin`

//Add below function in separate / common function file.

```
def check_role_permissions_admin(request, url=None):
    if not hasattr(request.user,"client"):
        return {
            'clientwise': False,
            'add': False,
            'change': False,
            'delete': False,
            'view': False,
            'icon': ''
        }
    super_admin_role = Role.objects.get(pk=1)
    all_roles = request.user.groups.all()
    try:
        action = Actions.objects.get(
            url=url
        )
    except:
        action = None
    if super_admin_role in all_roles:
        return {
            'clientwise': False,
            'add': True,
            'change': True,
            'delete': True,
            'view': True,
            'icon': str(action.icon) if action else ''
        }

    // Write Logic here for Role and Permissions of requested action(s)
    roles = [group for group in request.user.groups.all()]
    permissions = ActionPermissions.objects.filter(
        client=request.user.client,
        role__in=roles,
        action__url=url
    )
    if permissions.exists():
        permobj = permissions[0]
        return {
            'clientwise': True if permobj.client else False,
            'add': True if permobj.add else False,
            'change': True if permobj.change else False,
            'delete': True if permobj.delete else False,
            'view': True if permobj.view else False,
            'icon': permobj.action.icon
        }
    else:
        return {
            'clientwise': False,
            'add': False,
            'change': False,
            'delete': False,
            'view': False,
            'icon': ''
        }
```

//Add below code in admin.py, for every admin action you need to do following //thing and need
//to make sure that similar entry is added in table permissions.

```
from module.function import check_role_permissions_admin
@admin.register(ConfigRuleMaster)
class ModelMasterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    action_form=CustomActionForm
    form = ModelMasterForm
    fields=(('title','template'))
    list_display=('title','template')
    search_fields = ('title','template',)
    list_display_links = []

    def get_model_perms(self, request):
        perms = decorators.check_role_permissions_admin(request, '/admin/lmt/modelmaster/')
        perms['clientwise'] = False
        return perms

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        perms = decorators.check_role_permissions_admin(request, '/admin/lmt/modelmaster/')
        return perms['add']

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        perms = decorators.check_role_permissions_admin(request, '/admin/lmt/modelmaster/')
        return perms['change']
```

5. Another work is to handle actions through decorators.

But this is very raw version of code I found in my repository, you need to make this logic at very high level to make your client happy and to have full secured code.